# jquery animation in a loop returns same index

Tags: javascript, jquery, loops

I have a problem here with an animation inside a loop. The output is like it should be i guess but not kow i want.

```
for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
  $('#slot-'+i).animate({
    marginTop: -10
  }, 200, function() {
    console.debug(i);
    if (i == 0) somefunction();
  });
}
```

The problem is that console.debug(i) outputs the last index of the for loop everytime.

What I want to achive is: In the complete function of the animation i want to call a function - BUT ONLY ONCE.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
for (var i = 0; i < slots.length; i++) {
    $('#slot-' + i).animate({
        marginTop: -10
    }, 200, (function(count) {
        return function() {
            console.debug(count);
            if (count == 0) somefunction();
        };
    })(i));
}
```

The problem here is that unless you use an immediately invoked function expression that **returns** the appropriate success handler for each iteration, all of your handlers will refer to the same value of i.

Comment: This is a good answer, but its useful if you explain why this works for the benefit of all. Just dumping corrected code is less useful for future users.

Comment: yeah this answer is great.. it works. nevermind i guess its hard to describe but i keep this method in mind.

Comment: @Jamiec I have included an explanation, but in a recent conversation I found that my understanding of scope is somewhat flawed. If you have an in depth explanation or find anything wrong with my explanation, please do post an answer or comment here.

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
var i = 0;
for (i=0; i < slots.length; i++) {
$('#slot-'+i).animate({
    marginTop: -10
  }, 200, function() {
    console.debug(i);
    if (i == 0) somefunction();
  });
}
```

Comment: Is there anything different in your approach?

Comment: yeah he set the var first... i tried it but it failed :( the answer above works

Comment: I think in this case `var i` should be global then it can work and in my answer it is like global var so it should work.